# Compute $\sum _{i=0}^n \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^3=\frac{(n+1)^2}{4 n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

Can someone show me how one can deal with this get the answer provided?
$$\sum _{i=0}^n \left(\frac{i}{n}\right)^3=\frac{(n+1)^2}{4 n}$$
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equality is equivalent to

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^3=\frac14 n^2(n+1)^2$$
and we can prove it by induction. For the inductive step we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} i^3=\sum_{i=1}^n i^3+(n+1)^3=\frac14 n^2(n+1)^2+(n+1)^3=\cdots\cdots$$

Comment: If you only had left hand side as of what I have provided how would you go about simplifying it to the right hand side

Comment: are you able to factor out 1/n? and would it be 1/n or 1/n^3?

Comment: For your first question the idea is to write the telescoping  sum on two ways:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n(i+1)^4-i^4$$
and for your second question: Yes since $\frac1{n^3}$ is a constant: it doesn't depend on $i$.

Comment: Why to the power of 4?

Comment: power $4$ will be simplified and there will be only  the power $3,2,1$ of $i$.

Comment: A perfect that makes sense! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Multiply both sides by $n^3$, then use complete induction.